# display the phone contacts only in windows phone 8

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

It is possible to replace a contact filter kind to contact storage kind in cons.SearchAsync.
C# code:

```
FilterKind contactFilterKind = FilterKind.None;
    StorageKind contactStorageKind = StorageKind.Phone;

        ContactResultsData.DataContext = this.DisplayedContacts;
        ContactResultsLabel.Text = "results are loading...";
        ContactResultsData.DataContext = null;



        Contacts cons = new Contacts();

       // ContactResultsData.DataContext = cons;
        cons.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(Contacts_SearchCompleted);

        cons.SearchAsync(contactFilterString.Text, contactFilterKind, "Contacts Test #1");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chakravathy you can't replace **contactFilterKind** with **contactStorageKind**  because 
**cons.SearchAsync** defination only accepts **FilterKind** parameter so it can't be anything else..